# using wp_insert_term to create custom terms for a custom taxonomy from frontend form,

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, front-end

I have a form which allows certain roles to add custom terms to a taxonomy.

My taxonomy is called Genre (slug genre)

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="text" value="" name="new">
    <input type='submit' name='Save'>
</form>
```

I have been going around in circles with this for hours. Ive searched for other questions similar and have tried the suggestions.

I am using https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/ to create the custom taxonomies - Was wondering maybe my script is firing before this plugin does and therefore wp_insert_terms happens before the register of the custom taxonomy?

My PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['save']) && !empty($_POST)) {

    $term = ($_POST['new']);
        
    
      $existent_term = term_exists( $term, 'genre' );

    if( $existent_term && isset($existent_term['term_id']) ) {

        $term_id = $existent_term['term_id'];

    } else {

        //insert the term if it doesn't exsit
        $term = wp_insert_term(
            $term, // the term 
            'genre' // the taxonomy
        );
        if( !is_wp_error($term ) && isset($term['term_id']) ) {
             $term_id = $term['term_id'];
        } 

   }

} //end isset
```

Nothing shows in the error log either.

Has anyone come across this issue before? or is anyone able the assist please

Ive tried things like setting `$term = ($_POST['new']);` to `$term = "music";` and having the input value like  `<input type="text" value="music" name="new">`

Also I have tried with an array

```
wp_insert_term(
    $term,   // the term 
    'genre', // the taxonomy
    array(
        'description' => 'I am description.',
        'slug'        => 'music',
       
    )
);
```

Comment: How/when/where does your PHP code run? It should be hooked into a hook that runs after `init`.

Comment: Im currently running it on the page which the form site on, Do you think I should do this as function in the functions.php?

Comment: You mean, the code is in your page template? Try adding `var_dump( taxonomy_exists( 'genre' ) );`, e.g. after the `$term = ($_POST['new']);`, and see what the dump says.

Comment: Yes, the code is in the page template, The form and then code below the form. 
I added var_dump( taxonomy_exists( 'genre' ) ); and nothing shows.

Comment: Actually, the problem seems to be the `$_POST['save']` because the input name is `Save` (note the uppercase "S")..

Comment: I can not believe I missed that! Thank you. I guess sometimes when you sit looking at something for too long you miss the obvious. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. But I would actually use 1) `if( isset($_POST['Save']) && !empty($_POST['new']) ) {`, and 2) `if( is_array( $existent_term ) && isset($existent_term['term_id']) )`. I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: It does, thank you